# Including functions in Drools declared types

Tags: java, drools

Is there a way to add member functions to a Drools declared type? That is, I'd like to say something like:

```
declare Foo
  bar : int
  plugh : String
  function String greeting()
  {
    return "Hello "+plugh+"!";
  }
end
```

That doesn't work (or I wouldn't be writing this post), but do I just have the syntax wrong, or is there no way to do that in Drools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include functions in a Drools declared type (above and beyond what it generates in the class to support Bean property types). If you find you need functions in a declared type you should probably create them in your regular Java then import them into your rule file.